# react-bootstrap modal called multiple in .map looping

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-bootstrap

Hi i just start using react-bootstrap. what I need to do is to loop a list of movie then each row will show a modal of movie detail.

here is my compnent with .map loop for movie list:

```
                    {   
                        this.state.movies
                        ? this.state.movies.map((object, i)=>{
                            return (
                                <div obj={object.imdbID} key={i}>
                                    <ListGroup.Item>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col md={5}>
                                                <MovieModal key={i} 
                                                    onShowModal = {this.handleShowModal}
                                                    onHideModal = {this.handleHideModal}
                                                    modal = {this.state.modal}
                                                    movie = {object}
                                                    index = {i}
                                                ></MovieModal>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col md={2}>{object.Year}</Col>
                                            <Col md={3}>{object.imdbID}</Col>
                                            <Col md={2}>
                                                {
                                                    object.Fav
                                                    ? <img src={`../assets/golden-star.png`} alt="star"></img>
                                                    : <img src={`../assets/star.png`} alt="star"></img>
                                                }
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </ListGroup.Item>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })

                        : <h1>not found</h1>
                    }
```

and here is modal component

```
            <div>
                <p onClick={this.props.onShowModal}>{this.props.movie.Title} {this.props.index}</p>
                <Modal show={this.props.modal} onHide={this.props.onHideModal} backdropClassName={'modal-backdrop'}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{this.props.movie.Title} {this.props.index}</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <h1>test body</h1>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <h1>test footer</h1>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
```

the modal already called, but it seems like loop for the rest of movie. the modal looks like stack of modals and show the last one. and here is my console shows when I click the modal's trigger.

````
Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: 

```

I already make sure the function works well, it tested without looping. what should I do to make it just show one modal when I click?
````

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a modal that displays a list of movies.

Your code creates multiple modals because you are rendering a movie modal on each loop.

Try it the other way around. Embed the list within the modal.

---

```
const movies = {} // I'm assuming you have your movies object in a const

// use object deconstruction to create a list of ListGroup.Items
const MovieList = ({ movies }) => 
    movies.map( (movie, index) => (
        <ListGroup.Item key={movie.imdbID}>
            <Row>
                <Col md={2}>{movie.Year}</Col>
                <Col md={3}>{movie.imdbID}</Col>
            </Row>
        </ListGroup.Item>
    ));

... render ( ...

            <div>
                <p onClick={this.props.onShowModal}>{this.props.movie.Title} {this.props.index}</p>
                <Modal show={this.props.modal} onHide={this.props.onHideModal} backdropClassName={'modal-backdrop'}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{this.props.movie.Title} {this.props.index}</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <ListGroup>                          {/* <----- put your list const here */}
                            <MovieList movies={movies} />
                        </ListGroup>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <h1>test footer</h1>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I think something wrong when asking the question. what actually I want is to show a list of movies and put a click trigger on each row to show modal which consists of the detail of the movie. when calling the modal I pass id-like to the modal when the trigger clicked. My code works, but it seems like it calls the entire modal for each row. No error shows in terminal and browser, but my console shows this warning when the trigger clicked: Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.

Comment: @ilhamkurnia I can help you further debug. Can you post a complete MWE in your question, with a link to an interpreter (jsfiddle, codesandbox)?

Comment: I'm new at React it confused me to put the code there and also the project using some library. how about I share my Github repository?

Comment: if it's okay, here is the repository https://github.com/ilhamksyuriadi/favorite-movie

Comment: Hi Harley Lang, I already solve it with store the data on parent state, thanks for answering me ^^

Comment: Of course @ilhamkurnia, I am happy to help! Before we round out this discussion, can you update your question with a complete MWE and your solution?  This may aid others who stumble on this page in the future!